# How to prevent a combo box from selecting a value

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm using a ComboBox with the DropDownStyle = "DropDownList". Programatically I set the DataSource for the items in the list. Something like this :

```
combo.DisplayMember = "Text";
combo.ValueMember = "id";
combo.DataSource = ds.tbl;
```

The list is populated correctly and the first element is selected. How do I prevent the first element from being selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Ho, right. I knew that. I just didn't though about it because of another problem I have with another combobox on the same form. I'll create a separate question to explain this other problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set `SelectedIndex` to -1. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx